# Jquery Toggle with Div Slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

well i was planning to do something like this:

http://www.bluefountainmedia.com/portfolio

That every time you click on the image, the div below will show, and if im going to click other images, it'll toggle back up, then open the next portfolio with the same div but different images and descriptions on the side.

Note: they have the same div, just calling out different items.

Thank you.

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: @chris85: How would i be able to make that kind of slider? the one i made was just fadeToggle but im using different divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you look at the console, they are calling different divs.  You could probably get it done quickly using jQuery [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) / [.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/).